# “Why it means so much to me?” or “Why does it mean so much to me?”

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

> 1. "Why the hell it means so much to me?" or
> 2. "Why the hell **does** it mean so much to me?"

Which is correct and why?
If wrong, is the first phrase at least informally acceptable?

Comment: I changed the formatting a little bit. You are also encouraged to include your research and understanding in every post (sometimes required). See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

Comment: In direct questions - even ones that are rhetorical - we invert the verb and the subject. Unless there is already an auxiliary (_be_, _have_, a modal) or the verb is _be_ (or for some speakers, _have_) this requires inserting a suitable form of the auxiliary _do_ before the subject: hence "why does it mean", not "why it means"

Comment: Colin, your comment should become an answer!

Answer (score -1):

Turn your question back into a statement and see which one fits.

> 1. "Why ... it means so much to me?" => It means so much to me.
> 2. "Why ... **does** it mean so much to me?" => It does mean so much to me.

Since the 1st one seems like a better choice, I suggest using the 1st one.

Comment: I don't really agree with your second statement. My input: `It means so much to me` -> `Why does it mean so much to me?` This is just a simple Wh question. Moreover, I don't think the 1st question is formally accepted as one.

Comment: Disagree.  Can you edit your answer to provide better support or references than simply “one seems like a better choice “?